# Abelian rings question

Tags: ring-theory

I have to prove that the ring $(B,+,*)$ is abelian only when for every $(a,b) \in B^2$, $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$.

I don't know where to start, and also I can relate $*$ to the ring, not $+$.

Comment: You were missing a $2$ in the formula - it is certainly not the case in all abelian rings that $(a+b)^2=a^2+ab+b^2$.

Comment: Although we talk about *Abelian groups*, for rings it's *commutative rings*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Write out $$(a+b)^{2}=(a+b)(a+b)=a^{2}+ab+ba+b^{2}$$

note that
in general you have to multiply this way since in some rings $ab\neq ba$
.

Now assume $$(a+b)^{2}=a^{2}+2ab+b^{2}$$ and compare both calculations.
What do you get ?

Comment: So,since we have * in the ring, I can write (a+b)*(a+b),which is = a^2+ab+ba+b^2 ,and compared to (a+b)^=a^2+2ab+b^2...i do the math and I have ab=ba so,yes this is an abelian ring,thanks!

Comment: @Alone1990 - I'm glad that helps! :)

Answer (score 2):

Let $a,b\in B$. Then your hypothesis is that $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$. So
$$
a^2+2ab+b^2=(a+b)^2=a^2+ab+ba+b^2.
$$
Since we can cancel additive terms, we get
$$
2ab=ab+ba;
$$
subtracting $ab$ from both sides, we get $ab=ba$.

Answer (score 0):

Similarly, and more simply, the $ $ *difference of squares* $ $ formula is equivalent to commutativity

$$\rm\begin{eqnarray} a^2-b^2 &=&\,\rm (a-b)\,(a+b) \\  &=&\,\rm ab-ba\, +\, a^2-b^2 \\
\iff\ 0\, &=&\,\rm ab-ba \end{eqnarray}$$